# Background color does not show up when scrolling to the right

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have the following simple HTML and CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 970px;">Text area</div>
    <div style="height: 20px; background-color:gray; width: 100%; "></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I load this page in a browser. If the width of the browser is 400px (just an example), then I see a horizontal scroll bar in the browser screen bottom. If I move the scroll bar to the right, I can see that the background of the second div does not extend to the right.

**I hope that the background color of the second div can extend from browser's left edge to the right edge (no matter what the width of the browser is).**

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: this is weird. trying to find some fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever an element's explicitly set width is larger than the width of the `body`, the element overflows the `body`'s boundaries.  In other words, the browser will not adjust the width of the `body`, thereby restructuring an entire page layout, because one element spills over.

One solution is to make the `div` that follows the first `div` overflow as well.

Here's HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>Text area</div>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body > div:first-of-type {
    width: 970px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

body > div:last-of-type {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
    body > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        width: 970px;    
    }
}
```

And, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8mK7f/.

Comment: DRD, the solution does not work. As said in the post, I need the second div to extend from browses's left edge to its right even when the browser's width is more than 970px. Fiddle does not show the correct results if you increase the width of the lower-right page in fiddle beyond 970px. Thanks soooo much for help!!! –

Comment: Yes, it does work.  Your screen could be a bit small to incorporate the fiddle preview screen beyond 970px.  Here's a different fiddle with textarea div sized to 340px and with media queries code adjusted accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/zX33r/.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve like this:

```
<div style="width: 970px">
  <div>Text area</div>
  <div style="height: 20px; background-color:gray; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work. As said in the post, I need the second div to extend from browses's left edge to its right even when the browser's width is more than 970px.  Thanks soooo much for help!!! –

Comment: @curious1 Then you should use relative sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making sure the browser default CSS isn't interfering by using a CSS reset. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `body` tag's width is the width of your browser window, and the 100% width on the second div is taking the width of the parent, which is the `body` tag. In your example this means the second div will only ever be 400px (the width of the browser window).

You'll have to set the width of the `body` tag to also be `970px` in order for this to work. Setting `body` to `100%` width won't solve it, because that will take 100% of it's parent width which is the `html` tag and will still be the width of the browser window.

```
<body style="width: 970px;">
    <div style="width: 970px;">Text area</div>
    <div style="height: 20px; background-color:gray; width: 100%; "></div>
</body>
```

EDIT: An alternative is to set the `body` to have `display: inline-block` which will force it to expand to the width of it's children:

```
<body style="display:inline-block">
    <div style="width: 970px;">Text area</div>
    <div style="height: 20px; background-color:gray; width: 100%; "></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The width of the second div stops at 970px width. I want it to extend from side to side, no matter what the size of the browse is. I stated it in my post. Thanks!!!

Comment: @curious1 the second solution should work for you. Setting the body to `display: inline-block` will force it to be the width of it's children, which means the second div will get that width. Here's a fiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/Rk8As/

Comment: Dave, it does not work. As said in the post, I need the second div to extend from browses's left edge to its right even when the browser's width is more than 970px. Fiddle does not show the correct results if you increase the width of the lower-right page in fiddle beyond 970px. Thanks soooo much for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you use percentages in CSS, it only extends to the % of the parent element.  In this example, make sure that the body element is 100% width as well.

Best of luck :)

Comment: I added style="width: 100%;" to the body tag. It does not work. What did I miss? Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

Since you are hard coding the widths why not just set the width of the gray bar to the same as the div >Text Area< ? 
e.g

```
<div style="width: 970px;">Text area</div>
<div style="height: 20px; background-color:gray; width: 970px; "></div>
```

Comment: Does not work. I want the second div to extend from side to side no matter what the browse width is. I said in my post. Thanks!